# Sqlite3 shell output: word wrap single columns

Tags: bash, shell, sqlite, word-wrap

I am interacting with a sqlite3 database on linux with bash scripts. It is a small tool I use for myself. I am displaying the data in the terminal. Some of the columns contain a lot of text, too much to show in a single line. Is there a possibility to word wrap the output of the select-query? The output I am looking for should look something like this:

```
rowid | column1     | column2      | column3
------------------------------------------------
1     | value 11    | value 21     | value 31
------------------------------------------------
2     | value 12    | This is a    | value 32
      |             | very long    |
      |             | text         |
------------------------------------------------
3     | value 13    | value 23     | value 33
------------------------------------------------
4     | value 14    | value 24     | value 34
```

Is there a possibility to do this? I was not able to find a solution to this problem. Thanks in advance and BR!

Comment: Perl's [`format` with fill mode](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html#Using-Fill-Mode) could do it but you'd probably have to make quite a few changes to your existing code.

Comment: I am not familiar with perl and how to integrate it in my bash script, this would take too much time for me to implement under the circumstances I am in. Thank you anyways, @jhnc!